# Unable to run cucumber scripts through jenkins- Cucumber: command not found

Tags: ruby, shell, jenkins, cucumber

**Build Log**

> /Users/alanbaldwin/RubymineProjects/webclientFrameworkCucumber
>   [webclientFrameworkCucumber] $ /bin/sh -xe
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson5297293434162456733.sh
>   + cucumber features/API_data_hub.feature /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson5297293434162456733.sh: line 2:
>   cucumber: command not found Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as
>   failure Finished: FAILURE

I am trying to set up and run my cucumber tests through Jenkins. However, I keep getting a build failure message as above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Cucumber executable is not on your path.

Check the RubyGems path by `gem env` and update your path.